# Pushing scripts with landscape server to client failed with Group activity failed error

Tags: 16.04, scripts, error-handling, landscape

My workstation was added to the relevant group that is assigned to the script ...
bit on the events section I see that action failed with this error:

```
Group activity failed
```

Has anyone faced it before ?
Where can I check some detailed logs ?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with a quickstart version

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Idan! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In order to increase your chance of a good answer, put more information in your post. What script you invoked; what was the command; are there more outputs from the script?

Comment: Please do not ask for other affected people on [ubuntu.se] (“someone has faced it before?”), ask for the solution.